# Primefaces datatable LazyDataModel create new row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazydatamodel

I have a primefaces datatable which uses LazyDataModel instead Collection.

I need to implement a button which create a new row in the table (empty row in last row of actual page in datatable).

I have tried adding.

```
@Component("table")
@Scope("session")
public class TablaPaginada implements Serializable {
    private LazyDataModel<User> users;
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        usuarios = new LazyDataModel<User>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8885722005055879976L;
            @Override
            public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
                    SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                List<User> data = getUsers(first, pageSize, sortOrder, filters);
                return data;
            }
        };
        users.setRowCount(totalRowUsers());
    }
    public void newRow() {
        //I would do this if it was List instead LazyDataModel
        //this.users.add(new User());
        users.getWrappedData().add(new User()); //this does not work.
    }
}
```

This would be the xhtml code:

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" value="#{table.users}" var="user" paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             rows="5" lazy="true">

    <p:column headerText="id" sortBy="#{user.id}" filterBy="#{user.id}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="name" sortBy="#{user.name}" filterBy="#{user.name}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="lastName" sortBy="#{user.lastName}" filterBy="#{user.lastName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="money" sortBy="#{user.money}" filterBy="#{user.money}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.money}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="new row" action="#{table.newRow()}" update="@form"/>
</h:form>
```

EDIT:

my code does not create new row.

Comment: What went wrong with your code? You just state what you did, not what happens.

Answer (score 1):

From PF documentation: `<p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{dtBasicView.addCar}"
oncomplete="PF('dt').addRow()" process="@this"/>`

And for Lazy Datatable you may run into this issue which has a workaround: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3901